# Sup Norm using FT

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

For some proper signal $x(t)$ the Fourier transform is given
$$X(\omega)\equiv\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int dt x(t) e^{-i\omega t}$$
Is there a $simple$ way to write down the sup norm of the signal in time domain
$$||x||_\infty\equiv \sup_t |x(t)|$$
in terms of its FT? That is without using the inverse FT ofcourse.

Comment: You said without using the inverse Fourier transform...what is wrong with using the Fourier inversion formula to get that $\|x\|_\infty\leq (2\pi)^{-1/2}\|X\|_{L^1}?$ That seems like the most natural way to get this sort of information.

Comment: Or are you asking for an exact relationship, not a bound?

Comment: @cmk I was actually looking for an exact relationship. But your bound is also new for me. thanks already.